Numero basura al inicializar una variable en c
tengo este problemita.
Desde hace un tiempo empece a estudiar C y tenia la idea de que el codigo -->
int mayor, menor = 0;

Siempre pense que mayor se inicializa con el 0 que le pongo a menor.
Pero por ejemplo en el siguiente codigo -->
int may, men = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    if (altura[i] > prom){
      may += 1;
    }else if (altura[i] < prom){
      men += 1;
    }
  }

El numero inicializado es un numero desconocido (basura). Claramente se que se pongo el "mayor = 0" se soluciona todo. Pero alguien me podria explicar por que el mayor no se inicializa con el 0 que le doy al menor?
Gracias!!!!

No hay mucho que explicar. Ya lo descubriste. La asignación siempre es a una sola variable, la que está inmediatamente a la izquierda del operador =.  Debería ser int may = INT_MAX, men = 0;

Realmente pasa eso porque es la sintaxis establecida para las declaraciones en C/C++. Es la que es, independientemente de que nos parezca más o menos intuitiva o apropiada. Podría funcionar de otra forma si el estándar lo especificara así. A grandes rasgos, ignorando los atributos de C++11 y manteniéndonos con declaraciones simples:
decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list (optional) ;    


Los especificadores de declaración son una secuencia de especificadores separados por espacios, en nuestro ejemplo el único especificador es el tipo (int).

init-declarator-list es una secuencia separada por comas de uno o más init-declarators, que a su vez consta de un declarador (que no es más que un identificador en este caso) y un inicializador (opcional generalmente).


El inicializador va unido al declarador, a cada identificador, por lo que:
int mayor, menor = 0;

es equivalente a:
int mayor;
int menor = 0;

Lo que lógicamente deja a mayor sin inicializar y su uso entraña un comportamiento indefinido.
Debes asociar el inicializador a cada identificador:
int mayor = 0, menor = 0;
int mayor(0), menor(0); // C++ (constructor initialization)
int mayor{0}, menor{0}; // C++11 (uniform initialization)

Hay otro error relacionado con esto muy típico, que tiene que ver con los operadores que pueden modificar a cada declarador como &, *, [] o (), por ejemplo:
int* n, m;

declara un puntero a un entero (n) y un entero (m), no dos punteros a entero.
Se puede decir que pertenecen sintácticamente al símbolo/identificador y no al tipo, por lo que mucha gente prefiere escribirlo como int *n, m;, aunque al compilador le da lo mismo...
Si quieres profundizar algo más, quizás esta página te resulte útil.

En la declaración int mayor, menor = 0;, la variable mayor no está inicializada explícitamente, mientras que menor está inicializada con el valor 0.
El valor de la variable mayor será indeterminado, ya que no se le asigna explícitamente ningún valor. Aunque muchos compiladores inicializan variables no inicializadas con cero, no está garantizado por C y depende de la implementación del compilador.

El sistema operativo puede asignar memoria para variables no
inicializadas con cero como un comportamiento estándar, pero en C no
está garantizado que el valor proveniente de la memoria para la
variable no inicializada sea cero; puede ser cualquier número y no
solo 0.

Usando el compilador gcc como referencia, aunque en la documentación oficial no se menciona que la falta de declaración explícita en variables no inicializadas pueda tener el valor cero, lo que se considera más es la optimización del compilador para inicializar con el patrón de memoria del sistema operativo.
Los sistemas Windows y Linux inicializan la memoria asignada con ceros, y cuando se declara una variable sin inicializar, el lugar correspondiente en la memoria se llenará con 0, lo cual es un comportamiento garantizado pero no confiable.

La gran diferencia en la instrucción, es si estas declarando o estas definiendo las variables cuanto escribes int mayor; estas solamente declarando, cuando le asignas el valor lo que estas haciendo es definiendo la variable, esto es importante porque puedes estar generando errores, que luego son difíciles de detectar, si estas buscando la especificación,La referencia específica a este comportamiento se puede encontrar en el estándar C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011): Sección 6.7.9 (Inicialización):
Cuando se usan inicializadores en una declaración, solo la variable que sigue inmediatamente a la inicialización recibe el valor asignado.

Realmente no, lo que haces es pedirle al sistema operativo una memoria que quepa un entero. El sistema operativo solo te la dá, sin verificar que valor tuviera previamente. Por lo que no se sabe que valor la variable sin inicializar.
